# Why perl do not allow %hash, @array arguments for subroutines?

Tags: perl

There is no technical reason to not allow `@array` and/or `%hash` as argument to subroutine. For example: `push @list, 1, 2`, - allow that.

We can achieve that with [prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes):

```
mypop (\@)
```

But all the same we get that array/hash as reference:

```
sub test (\%\@) {
    my( $hash, $array ) =  @_;
    ...
```

What is the historical reason to not allow next?

```
my( %hash, @array ) =  @_;
```

And what is the benefit of prohibiting this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl is a largely list-oriented language, and distinguishes between singular and plural context. A subroutine argument list is a plural context. An array or hash in plural context is a list of its values. So a call like `foo(@bar)` flattens the array into its elements. This flattening allows argument lists to be concatenated conveniently, e.g.:

```
@result = map { $_ * 2 } @nums, 3, 4, return_a_list(), @more_nums;
```

Note also that before Perl 5, there were no references that can be passed around. There were array *variables*, but not arrays as first-class values. Operators such as `push` operate on a array variable. With Perl 5, we have references so we can pass array references around wrapped in scalars. The array operators were re-defined to still parse array variables (or dereferencing expressions), but logically operate on references. So you can declare `sub mypush(\@@)` which will receive an array reference as first argument (when called in a way that respects this prototype).

Perl 6 uses an approach that is more familiar when coming from languages such as Python where arrays are first-class objects. There is less context, less flattening.

Comment: As I can see there is no any reason to prohibiting this. Perl just keep compatibility. And this is the only reason.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I think compatibility is a very good reason. It's unlikely Perl would have been designed like that today, even though this auto-flattening has a convenient shell-like feel to it (e.g. specifying shell command arguments like `foo $var` or `foo "$@"`). This can sometimes be confusing, up to having [security implications](https://blog.gerv.net/2014/10/new-class-of-vulnerability-in-perl-web-applications/). Since flattening is still useful, other languages like Python 3.5 support [explicit syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for this.

Comment: Yeah, I fall into this security issue once too. After that I have a question: Why in `key/value` the `=>` do not run its right operand in scalar context?? Often when function called such way: { a => fn() } and can return list will return even count of elements as result and this will cause runtime error. Thought this easy to fix sometimes it is not spotable (. Always in key/value context we intend scalar value. I thought to post this as feature request on `perlbug` but not sure about this idea yet.

Comment: @EugenKonkov There is no such thing as a key–value context, just list context. The `=>` is a comma that happens to parse barewords on the left as strings. For example, `use constant FOO => 1, 2, 3` defines a list constant. So `=>` cannot be changed to impose scalar context without massively breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: `use constant FOO => 1,2,3` we should not touch. I speak **only** about `key/value`. We can easily spot `{}` when parsing and setup some private flag to point `key/value` context. I saw similar hacks in source code of perl for `@_` magic to work. Then `use strict 'hash'` and enable by default for latest releases when `use Modern::Perl`. I think every body will happy if their code would not work if has security issue.

Comment: It seems [I am not alone](https://blog.gerv.net/2014/10/new-class-of-vulnerability-in-perl-web-applications/#comment-43476) about this. And `use strict 'hash'` should be considered seriously. What do you think?